# How to get data of formarray ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to get data of `mdTextBox` which is inside my formarray how do i get it here is code i wrote:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <ion-list>
    <div formArrayName="mdNames" style="background-color:white">

      <ion-list *ngFor="let obj of myForm.controls.mdNames.controls; let i=index">

        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <ion-item no-lines>

            <ion-input formControlName="mdTextBox" type="text" class="textFields" placeholder="Type details"></ion-input>

          </ion-item>

        </div>
      </ion-list>
</form>
```

code inside .ts file:

```
console.log("output is "+ <FormArray>this.myForm.get('mdNames.mdTextBox'));
```

output shows: null

i want output to be: `["1","22","33"]` if 3 `mdTextBox` are available

Where i am making mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use .map() function to convert

```
[{"mdTextBox":1},{"mdTextBox":22},{"mdTextBox":321}]
```

to

```
[1,22,321]
```

Comment: can you please write syntax to achieve ?

Comment: just Google it http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/transforming-arrays-with-array-map.html